# How to remove a View of another Class with I have called in Existing Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am developing an application in which I am using TabBarController to show five tab. Also in that five tab I am calling a one class to another class view by creating the object of that  class with initWithFrame method. It show the view of another class in the existing class but my problem is that is doesn't dismiss the view when I click some another tab and agin come back to the same tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Remove Your View in

```
  - (void)dealloc
   {     
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
   }
```

And Then Add New View In Each view Each time in

```
   - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
   {
   }
```

Comment: Hi friend Because I am using TabBarController, I am not able to call ViewWilldisappear or dealloc method

Comment: - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
   { //remove your All View And then Add new View Each Time. Remove All View using objects of View
   }

Answer (score 0):

Take an array in the app delegate method.When you are creating object then add the object to the array which is in app delegate.Whenever you don't need then take the app delegate array.And then remove that object's view from superview.

```
[[appdel.viewsArray ojectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

To use

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
       [yourUIView removeFromSuperview];
}
```